# display image selected for uploading in Chrome and mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, file-upload

In one of my web application I have to show the image which selected for uploading before it uploaded to the server , using javascript .

I had this code ... It is working pretty well and fine in Mozilla . But not in Safari or Chrome .. Please help

```
// Handle file while select a new file
$('#file').change(function(){
        $('#img_size').val((this.files[0].size)/1000000);
                   handleFiles(this.files);
});


// handle files

function handleFiles(files) {





   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];

    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
        continue;
    }


     var img=document.getElementById('fake_img');
     img.src = file;
     img.onload = function() {



    };



    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) {
            aImg.src = e.target.result;
        };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working fine in chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/PrNWY/13/

Its shows the selected image in chrome & FF.

**update**

you can check file reader capability with following code

```
// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
    alert('The File APIs are fully supported in this browser.');
 } else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
 }
```

In my safari it failed because of it is not supporting file API fully.