# javascript: show uploaded file without a trip to the backend

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to use

```
<input type="file" value="choose a photo">
```

and show the file immediately without first sending it to the backend ?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476583/display-image-selected-for-uploading-in-chrome-and-mozilla) might help you.

Answer (score -2):

No,It cannot be done with javascript as javascript is a client-side language.

First get data from the server and then show the data using javascript on the page.